# Finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra embeds into unramified $p$-adic ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-numbers

Let $R$ be a finitely generated ring, that is, a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra of finite type. Assume that $\operatorname{char}(R) = 0$. It follows from Noether's normalization lemma that $R$ can be embedded in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a $p$-adic field $K$ for all but finitely many primes $p$.

> (1) Is there a prime $p$ such that $R$ be embedded in $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is **unramified**? (2) If so, are there infinitely many such primes p?

Comment: Two points: (1) it is clear that $R$ must be a commutative domain, I forgot to add that hypothesis. Otherwise, Noether's normalization either doesn't apply or only gives us integrality. (eg. $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)$). (2) I was unware of Cassels' embedding theorem, which proves a way stronger statement: if $R$ is a finitely generated commutative domain, for infinitely many primes $p$ there is an embedding of $R$ into $\mathbb{Z}_p$ itself. I am unsure if I should keep the question or edit it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how Cassels proved it, but it doesn't seem difficult from a geometric perspective. First, by "generic smoothness", replacing $R$ with a localization $R[1/f]$ we may assume it is smooth over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbf{Z}$. Then, by some variant of Chebotarev's density theorem, for infinitely many primes $p$ there exists an $\mathbf{F}_p$-point, i.e. a homomorphism $\chi\colon R\to\mathbf{F}_p$. Now, $R$ embeds into its completion $\hat{R}_\chi$ with respect to the kernel of $\chi$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]]$ for some $n\geq 0$ (and we may take $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in R$). We now seek a continuous surjection $f\colon \hat{R}_\chi\to \mathbf{Z}_p$ whose restriction to $R$ is injective. Such a surjection is given by a tuple $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ of elements of $p\mathbf{Z}_p$. If a nonzero element of $R$ is in the kernel, it implies that the $a_i$ satisfy a polynomial equation with coefficients in $\mathbf{Q}$. It is therefore enough to choose the $a_i$ to be algebraically independent over $\mathbf{Q}$, which we can do since $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is uncountable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The argument seems to reflect geometrically what is going on with Cassels' proof, which uses a mix of Noether's normalization and Hensel's lemma. The primes avoided by the localization process are detected in the Noether normalization, the existence of an $\mathbb{F}_p$ point is again given by analytic methods and the fact that to embed the completion of $R$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ it suffices to find small algebraically independent units is shown using Hensel's lemma.